# Rake aborted (thin_parser.so)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, bitnami

I am using Bitnami Redmine installation. I've tried to extend Redmine by some plugin but RAKE commands failed.

```
C:\Bitnami\redmine-2.4.3-0\apps\redmine\htdocs>rake
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.3.1-x86-mingw32/lib/thin_parser.so
C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.3.1-x86-mingw32/lib/thin.rb:41:in `require'
C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.3.1-x86-mingw32/lib/thin.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've already checked BUNDLE command, moreover reinstalled THIN game. But it finishes with success, without resolving the above issue.
Any ideas what is improperly configured?

hint: if I comment this line in thin.rb, it will crash on mysql2.so

```
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause:

Te root cause is improperly version dependecies (I use Ruby 2.0.0, Windows 7 32 bit (also checked on 64bit version).

Probably there is internal incositency if you are using BITNAMI REDMINE setup.

Solution:
Install latest mysql2 driver and thin, then edit gem file in redmine directory to use those latest version. For me, currently it is:

```
[...]
    gem 'thin', '1.6.2'
[...]
    when 'mysql2'
    gem "mysql2", "0.3.15", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
[...]
```